# Mutate with case_when

Tags: r, case

```
data1 %>% 
mutate(generation = case_when(
 DOB %in% '1/1/1945' > '31/12/1967' ~ "baby_boomers"
 TRUE ~ "else" 
)
```

Could someone please show me  the correct way to code a case when with dates (but formatted in  `DOB = col_character()`,)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data1)`, if that is not too large. Your current code won't work because `%in%` takes a vector as input and including `>` is incorrect syntax. Are you trying to see whether a date falls between two other dates?

Comment: And you need to put your dates in the standard `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format. `DOB > '1945-01-01' & DOB < '1967-12-31' ~ "baby_boomers"`

Comment: (If you don't use standard date formats, then you can't use `>` and `<`. Your `DOB` can be in character class if you use a `YYYY-MM-DD` format because then alphabetical ordering is the same as date ordering. But `m/d/yyyy` won't work.)

Comment: Thanks Gregor, I changed the format to date (YYMMDD) and now says Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    new_DOB >'1945/01/01' & new_DOB < '1967/12/31' ~ "baby_boomer" (I change DOB to new_DOB with date format)

Comment: data1 %>% 
  mutate(generation = case_when(
    new_DOB >='1945/01/01' & new_DOB <= '1967/12/31' ~ "baby_boomer",
    new_DOB >= '1968/01/01' & new_DOB <= '1984/12/31' ~ "GenX",
    new_DOB >= '1985/1/01' & new_DOB <= '1997/12/31' ~ "Millennials",
    TRUE ~ "GenZ"
  ))
problem solved, thanks guys